# article.cls not found for some programs - possible texpath problem

Tags: texlive, article, inkscape, debian

I have TexLive 2022 installed under /usr/local/texlive/2022/ on my Linux system.

I installed this from the vanilla sources and then created the dummy Debian package using the process shown on [TeXLive website](https://tug.org/texlive/debian.html).

Before anyone suspects that it is because of vanilla installation (as opposed to using outdated Debian packages), I would like to state that I have used this setup for years. The problem did not occur until 2022 version. None of the problems described below existed for TeXLive 2021 and earlier.

I have set the PATH variable correctly etc. I have the following texconfig output:

```
=========================== version information ==========================
TeX Live (https://tug.org/texlive) version 2022

==================== binaries found by searching $PATH ===================
PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/home/thunder/Private/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021b/bin:/home/thunder/Private/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2021b/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin
kpsewhich: /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/kpsewhich
updmap: /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/updmap
fmtutil: /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/fmtutil
texconfig: /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/texconfig
tex: /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tex
pdftex: /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/pdftex
mktexpk: /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/mktexpk
dvips: /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/dvips
dvipdfmx: /usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/dvipdfmx

=========================== active config files ==========================
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.ps
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex-ini-files/pdftexconfig.tex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/fmtutil.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/mktex.cnf
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/xdvi/XDvi

============================= font map files =============================
psfonts.map: /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/psfonts.map
pdftex.map: /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map
ps2pk.map: /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap/ps2pk.map

=========================== kpathsea variables ===========================
TEXMFMAIN=/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist
TEXMFDIST=/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist
TEXMFLOCAL=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFSYSVAR=/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var
TEXMFSYSCONFIG=/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-config
TEXMFVAR=/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-var
TEXMFCONFIG=/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-config
TEXMFHOME=/home/thunder/texmf
VARTEXFONTS=/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-var/fonts
TEXMF={{}/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/thunder/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist}
SYSTEXMF=/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var:/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local:/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist
TEXMFDBS={!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist}
WEB2C={{}/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/thunder/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist}/web2c
TEXPSHEADERS=.:{{}/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/thunder/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist}/{dvips,fonts/{enc,type1,type42,type3}}//
TEXCONFIG={{}/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/thunder/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist}/dvips//
ENCFONTS=.:{{}/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/thunder/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist}/fonts/enc//
TEXFONTMAPS=.:{{}/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-config,/home/thunder/.texlive2022/texmf-var,/home/thunder/texmf,!!/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-config,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var,!!/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist}/fonts/map/{kpsewhich,pdftex,dvips,}//

==== kpathsea variables from environment only (ok if no output here) ====
```

I use emacs + AucTeX as my production environment. The setup works correctly when I launch emacs from a terminal (instead of from Plasma GUI). This is a hint that something is off.

Now, when I try to use QTikZ or the extension TexText in Inkscape, my attempts to use tex input fail with the identical error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found.



Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
```

Initially, I thought that it was a bug in QTikZ. But given the odd behavior with Emacs, and the identical error in both the TeX using applications, I think that something is wrong in paths somewhere.

I think I messed up something subtle in an update (perhaps in the TeXLive update, or even earlier, when I reinstalled my system), but QTikZ has not worked for a few months, which tells me that the mistake was made some time back. I can compile documents from terminal, or in emacs launched from terminal, but nothing beyond.

Please help me debug this.

Comment: Check the PATH variable used by QTikZ

Comment: @egreg does that even make a difference of the error is `! LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found` then it would appear that `(pdf)latex` is found but not the classes?

Comment: @daleif it would if it is picking up some stub which does not come from tl2020

Comment: "The setup works correctly when I launch emacs from a terminal (instead of from Plasma GUI)." usually means you have set PATH at the wrong level so it is set in a shell started in a command window such as xterm, but not set in the shell that launched the GUI

Comment: @David Carlisle Thanks. I included the config in my question. Could you point to a possible location where it is misconfigured so that I could start debugging?